# Can Twitter tweets be crawled Using One's Own Crawler?

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

I want to crawl the tweets from twitter for sentimental analysis and want to know if by using my own crawler and without OathAuthentification i.e by registering my app on twitter can I crawl twitter

Comment: What method are you trying to use?

Comment: I am building a web crawler in python without using in built libraries like scrappy,bs4